# How can an element positioned behind its parent but still in front of its grandparent?

Tags: css, z-index

I have three elements stacked into each other. Now I want the innermost element to be placed behind its parent but still in front of its grandparent. I tried different variations on z-index settings, but had no succcess.

The code that shoul work as my understanding of z-index is:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: purple; position: relative; z-index: 1;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; position: relative; z-index: 1;">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative; z-index: -1;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Except that it does not.

Any solution?

Comment: @do you wants the playing cards effect??

Comment: Felix, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the position relative from the second div it will work

CSS

```
.div1{
  width: 400px; 
  height: 400px; 
  background-color: purple; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.div2{
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: blue;  
  z-index: 1;
}

.div3{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: green; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  left:150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='div1'>
    <div class='div2'>
        <div class='div3'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/MFULL/90/

Comment: is there a way yo make div3 appear behind div1 in this setup or do you have to add some divs?

Comment: @user2236165 if you remove the `position:relative` from the `div1` it will work since the stacking order will be defined higher up in the DOM structure. (see http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MFULL/97/)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean like:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use the following method:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZmvKX/

```
#a {
    width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #000;
    z-index: -1; position: absolute;
}

#b {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px 10px; top: 100px; left: 100px; background-color: #ff0;
    position: relative;
}

#c {
    width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px 10px; top: -50px; left: -50px; background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute; z-index: -2;
}
```

The trick is to get the stacking contexts right.

Answer (score 0):

As long as elements are part of the page flow, a parent can't be in front of it's children.

You would have to use absolute positioning to take the elements out of the page flow, to make it possible to stack them that way.

Comment: Guffa: Sorry, I should have posted a sample; of course they are positioned. See above.